# Crash involving presentViewController

Tags: ios

In my recent project, I used presentviewController to organize the switching of views. But there is a weird problem.

First I wrote a demo on git hub: [test present view](https://github.com/loadatom/ios-test/tree/master/test%20present%20view). Hope it'll make the problem easier to understand.

Second, I show what I did in the demo:
1) The root view controller is T1RootViewController, it has a property:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) T1TopViewController1 *top1VC;
```

When it loads, it adds T1TopViewController1 as its sole subview:

```
self.top1VC = [[T1TopViewController1 alloc] initWithNibName:@"T1TopView1" bundle:nil];
[self.view addSubview:self.top1VC.view];
```

2) T1TopViewController1 has a property:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) T1TopViewController2 *topVC2;
```

It also has a button, which present T1TopViewController2 when it's pressed:

```
self.topVC2 = [[T1TopViewController2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"T1TopView2" bundle:nil];
[self presentViewController:self.topVC2 animated:NO completion:nil];
```

3) T1TopViewController2 is almost the same as T1TopViewController1, except that it presents T1TopViewController3

4) T1TopViewController3 has a button, which will go back to show T1TopViewController1 when pressed:

```
UIWindow *rootWin = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
T1RootViewController *rootVC = (T1RootViewController *)rootWin.rootViewController;
[rootVC.top1VC dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
```

Then run this app, from T1TopViewController1, click button on each view until T1TopViewController3 appears. Then click T1TopViewController3 button, this will go back to T1TopViewController1. Then click the button on T1TopViewController1 again. Now a problem may occur:
1) On ios 5 simulator, all is fine
2) On ios 6.1 simulator or device, it'll crash, with a log:
test[699:c07] *** -[T1TopViewController2 isKindOfClass:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x75ade30

I really don't know what's wrong with my code, and how to fix it. I'll be very thankful for any help.

p.s. The dev environment is mac os x 10.8.4, xcode 4.6.3. The project enables ARC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I runned your app and I saw some weird things there, you have an UIViewController as RootViewController and then you initialize another UIViewController and add his UIView to the RootViewController's view.

Anyway here is what I've done:

You can change the code from your AppDelegate to this:

```
 T1TopViewController1 *cont = [[T1TopViewController1 alloc] initWithNibName:@"T1TopView1" bundle:nil];
 self.window.rootViewController = cont;
```

instead of what you had.

and the function:

```
- (IBAction)backBtn_onTouchUpInside:(id)sender
{
 UIWindow *rootWin = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
[rootWin.rootViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

from T1TopViewController3

Now you can change the controllers  as much as you want.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why your code doesn't work. But I have found a way to achieve what you want to do in your test project. If you exchange the action of the button in the `T1TopViewController3` to

```
- (IBAction)backBtn_onTouchUpInside:(id)sender
{
    UIViewController *presentingViewController = self.presentingViewController;
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{
        [presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
    }];
}
```

it should work.